# Find conditional probability of visiting a state in Continuous-Time-Markov-Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

Given a state space {$1, 2, 3, 4$}, and the  generator matrix:

$Q=\left(\begin{matrix}  -2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -3 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & -4 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 &-6  \end{matrix} \right)$

I'm trying to find $P(X_1 = 3|X_0 = 1)$ and $P(X_5 = 1,X_2 = 4|X_1 = 3)$,  but  am clueless how to  structure  both in the continuous-time setting?

For the first part,  I  found the embedded MC:

$P=\left(\begin{matrix}  0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\ 1/6 & 1/3 & 1/2 & 0  \end{matrix} \right)$

and $P(X_1 = 3|X_0 = 1)$ would  correspond to multiplying  by $\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right)$, and taking  the third column, i.e.  $1/2$. Is this  sound?

Comment: By $X_n$ do you mean the embedded chain? If so, use $P$ and proceed as usual.

Comment: Is this actually at time 1,2, etc. or after that number of jumps? The embedded DTMC is not useful in the former case because there can be an arbitrary number of jumps in a given interval. In the latter case it is straightforward to calculate using the transition probability matrix.

Comment: In R, I think the answer  is:

    expm(Q)[1,3]

= 21.6% to the first part...

Comment: Yes, if these are referring to the times then you need to use the matrix exponential, which is generally hard to evaluate exactly. For the second part, you want to write it as a product of things of the form $P(X_t=a \mid X_s=b)$.